# Knockout foreach is not creating child elements

Tags: knockout.js

The binding below works in that it creates the li and a elements as expected, but for some reason the i element nested inside the a element is not created. How do I tell knockout to create nested i element?

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TJdhW/3/ illustrates this. The li items are created without icons.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var item = function (p) {
            self = this;
            self.property = ko.observable(p);
        }
        var data = ko.observableArray([]);

        var test = new item("one");


        data().push(new item("one"));
        data().push(new item("two"));
        data().push(new item("three"));

        var vm = {
            data : data
        }


        ko.applyBindings(vm);
    });
</script>


<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" style="background-color: maroon;">ePM</a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-list"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-bar-chart"></i></a></li>

    <!-- ko foreach: data-->
    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" data-bind="text: property"><i class="icon-list" style="margin-right: 2px"></i></a></li>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-list" style="margin-right: 1px;"></i><i class="icon-plus"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-bar-chart" style="margin-right: 1px;"></i><i class="icon-plus"></i></a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TJdhW/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `data-bind="text: property"` an the `a` element which replaces the whole content of the link so it removes the icon and only displays the value of the `property` property.

In order to have both the text and the icon inside your anchor move the data-`bind="text: property"` inside the `a` (for example on a `span` element):

```
 <!-- ko foreach: data-->
        <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab" >
            <span data-bind="text: property"></span>
            <i class="icon-list" style="margin-right: 2px" ></i>
            </a>
        </li>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9U8mK/)